# How would one do async JavaScript setters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I'm trying to do asynchronous setters using async/await keywords.

Here some fakes database functions that takes time

```js
function getProjectFromDatabase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('My cool project!'), 500) // 500ms latency
    });
}

function setProjectToDatabase(projectName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('set!'), 500) // 500ms latency
    });
}
```

Here is an example of implementation for the user

```js
let user = {

    // Getter
    get project() {
        return (async () => {
            return await getProjectFromDatabase();
        })();
    },

    // Setter
    set project(projectName) {
        return (async () => {
            return await setProjectToDatabase(projectName);
        })();
    },

    // Method 
    setProject(projectName) {
        return (async () => {
            return await setProjectToDatabase(projectName);
        })();
    }
};
```

And here is an example of use

```js
(async function() {
    console.log(await user.project); // Getter works!
    await user.setProject('My new cool project!'); // Method works!
    await (user.project = 'Another project'); // Setter doesn't work...
})();
```

But the return value from the setter function seems ignored.
How could I do that?

Comment: Seems like these would be a bad fit for getter/setter properties.

Comment: `return (async () => { return await X; })();` is a really convoluted way of writing `return Promise.resolve( X );` (or just `return X;` when X is already a Promise).

Answer (score 2):

The assignment expression always evaluates to its right-hand side.

```
  a.b.c = "This is what it gets evaluated to"
```

there is no way to change that.

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally a setter *sets* some value and you don't care about the return value. In a traditional object this would be some other property (probably not intended to be used directly). Translated to something like a DB, the setter would post an INSERT or UPDATE and the new value would be set.

Your code in the setter isn't actually *setting* anything. If this were an actual DB call you would save some value in the database and then the next call to the getter would produce the new value. If you add something like this to the fan DB call, you will get something closer to traditional getter/setter logic:

```js
const a_user = {project: 'My cool project!'} // some fake db object

function getProjectFromDatabase() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(a_user.project), 500) // 500ms latency
    });
}

function setProjectToDatabase(projectName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            a_user.project = projectName // actually set something
            resolve(a_user.project)      // caller of setter doesn't care about return value, but we still need to resolve so async works.
        }, 500) // 500ms latency
    });
}
let user = {

    // Getter
    get project() {
        return (async () => {
            return await getProjectFromDatabase();
        })();
    },
    // Setter
    set project(projectName) {
        return (async () => {
            return await setProjectToDatabase(projectName);
        })();
    },

};

(async function() {
    console.log(await user.project); // Getter works!
    await (user.project = 'Another project'); // 
    console.log(await user.project); // new value has been set
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. However, the setter still does not work (it is not asynchronous) : `await (user.project = 'Another project'); console.log(a_user.project);` displays "My cool project!" and does not wait for the end of the promise

Comment: @Sharkou maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do. If you run the snippet, the output of the code above shows result of setting the property on user, which happens asynchronously. Both getter and setter are async. so you need to await in the console.log too.